# Escaping shell character in groovy jenkins pipeline

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, openshift

I have some issue to escape quote character in my jenkins pipeline. for example :

I want to append a text in to file through the pipeline using this command below:

```
openshift.rsh("${podname}", """sh -c 'echo "define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://rabah-test.com' );" >> wp-config.php'""")
```

and expecting this in to the wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://rabah-test.com' );
```

but unfortunately i don't have the quotes in my result :

```
define( WP_HOME, http://rabah-test.com );
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to deal with it. Instead of using simple quotes, I decided to use double quotes and escape with two backslashes.

Like this:

```
sh -c 'echo "define( \\" WP_HOME \\" , \\" http://rabah-test.com \\" );" >> wp-config.php'
```

And it now works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not an issue with jenkins. Try to run your command in the terminal first.
You have a simple quotes for your sh command and simple quotes inside the define.

I would try something like

```
sh -c 'echo "define( \'WP_HOME\', \'http://rabah-test.com\' );" >> wp-config.php'
```

Note, instead of adding the define to the wp-config.php file, I would be tempted to version a default WP_HOME and replace it by a sed

Comment: try in the terminal and work well but once again in the pipeline still not have the quotes